# Making tuple from pandas column name and value with list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a tuple from the following output using a list comprehension if possible.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns=['a','b'])
df.iloc[0]

Output:
a    1
b    2
```

This is the closest I can get so far:

```
[(x,y) for x in df.iloc[0].index for y in df.iloc[0]]

Output:
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

I know I can manually remove the `(a, 2)` and `(b, 1)`, but I wonder if there is a way to get the desired output without producing unnecessary results and filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you made mistake in your code, you took two loop aside where list has taken these loops as nested loop. Use instead `zip` to avoid nested loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]], columns=['a','b'])
[(x,y) for x,y in zip(df.iloc[0].index, df.iloc[0])]
```

**Ouput**

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

You can use also tuple

```
tuple(zip(df.iloc[0].index, df.iloc[0]))
```

Comment: I realized that this also works too...
`list(zip(df.iloc[0].index, df.iloc[0]))`

Comment: Absolutely and more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

For handling N rows...

```
 [(k,v[i]) for k,v in df.to_dict().items() for i in range(len(v))]
```